# circular reveal theme switcher like telegram in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am using DayNight theme in my application. And I have a button that changes the theme. In Telegram app there is a beautiful reveal animation that changes the theme without restarting activity or something like that. How to achieve this in flutter? and also the theme change should be persistent using shared preference and provider.[image]
i want to achieve something like this:-
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://medium.com/@tahamalas/animate-theme-change-with-circular-scale-animations-195836c42517) is what you are looking for

Comment: i have tried this package but some error is shown.i want any other method.

Comment: any other method?

Comment: Can anyone suggest another method?